# Accessing a list within a list

Tags: java, list, printing, compiler-construction, token

I'm trying to set up a scanner to recognize tokens and the problems is when I print it I get the following output.

```
[[@-1,0:6='PROGRAM',<1>,1:0], [@-1,8:11='sqrt',<2>,1:8], [@-1,13:17='BEGIN',<1>,2:0]
```

But I need output similar to the below one:

```
PROGRAM

sqrt

BEGIN
```

I've also listed my code below:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRFileStream("sqrt.micro");
        little lexer = new little(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);


            do {

                System.out.println((lexer.getAllTokens()));
                System.out.println("Value:" + lexer.getAllTokens());

                i++;



            }
            while(lexer.getAllTokens() == null);

        }
}
```

Comment: What does `lexer.getAllTokens()` return? Assuming that it returns list of tokens, you need to override `toString` method of token class. Also, you might need to print each item with newline instead of dumping whole list at once.

Comment: lexer.getAllTokens() is the function which provides the output in the horizontal format. What it does is it takes an input file from the user and recognizes the tokens and produces all the tokens into one list. I can't change the function because it is a pre-defined function. I just have to change the printing format where it prints what I need in a vertical format.

Comment: You don't need to change `lexer.getAllTokens()` method. But you need to override `toString` method in the class of `token`. Also, if you really want to print tokens line by line, you need to have a `for` loop over the list.

Answer (score -1):

You could alternatively use this regex to filter out the values /\'(.*?)\'/g

You can use the StreamAPI in combination with the regex to get the job done:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html